# Can i show all posts from one wordpress site to other wordpress site with separate domain as prefix to all posts?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have wordpress site with domain lets say **abc.com** and other wordpress site  on separate domain with separate database lets say **xyz.com**.
And all i want to get and show all existing posts from first domain to second domain.

For example: If a post is on first domain lets say **abc.com/post-1** then i want to show this post on second domain **xyz.com/post-1**.

**Edit 1:** All posts meta data, slug, content and featured image stored on first domain's database.

Comment: Something like this? I have no idea if it works, but it was an easy google find. https://distributorplugin.com/

Comment: @MrGlass will post slug from first domain work on second domain if i get all post data?

Comment: You'll have to read their website to see all that their plugin does. I have no affiliation with the plugin. If it doesn't meet your needs then you can clone it from github and change it to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the REST API tool: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/ to get the post list (json type) and then treat it on your website.